# Прелоадер для главной страницы

Tags: jquery

Есть главная страница и несколько внутренних. На главной странице есть прелоадер, который корректно отображается.
Можно ли как-то отменить запуск скрипта прелоадера, если перешли с внутренних страниц на главную? Повторно смотреть на прелоадер не логично. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Какой способ может помочь.

Comment: Перед запуском анимации прелоадера проверить, установлена ли cookie, например, `preloaderShown`. Если установлена, то пропустить анимацию, если не установлена, то запустить анимацию и установить cookie `preloaderShown`,

Comment: @AlexZhulin, а смысл, тогда с главной спадет прелоадер)

Comment: Alex Zhulin, я думал тоже о варианте с куками. Спасибо. Вот поставил. Как бы, всё работает, да. При запуске главной идёт прелоадер, после перехода с внутренних на главную, прелоадера уже нет. Это всё работает и хорошо. Но проблема в том, что не у всех же разрешено использования куков, кто-то это просто блокирует.) Есть какой-то выход из ситуации или вот есть то, что есть и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сверять значения текущего пути сайта со значением `/` с помощью `window.location.pathname`. Соответственно, прелоадер уже работает только при совпадении с корневым путем. Или использовать куки, как подсказали выше, если требуется одноразовый запуск.

Comment: Прелоадер есть только на главной странице.

Comment: @AlexZhulin, ох, невнимательно прочел задачу. Тогда да, Ваш вариант наиболее верный)